# Tokens not constructing properly

Tags: java, text, tokenize

im trying to tokenize text files using the following code:

```
    String fileContent = "";  
    String fileContentTokens[];  
    try{  
        fileContent = new Scanner(new File(fname)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();   
    } catch(Exception ex)  {  
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());  
    }  

    fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll("\\s*([,.?!\"'()-:*;])\\s*", " $1 ");
    //System.out.println(fileContent);
    fileContentTokens = fileContent.split(" ");
```

The problem is that the tokens are not forming properly, by that i mean that some words still have quotations attached with them some still have apostrophes. The code above is supposed to put gaps in between every punctuation so it's not attached to the word it self. For example: "That's cool" is supposed to be " That ' s cool ". But it's not doing that for some reason. It's only doing this for some of the words not all.

Comment: i did print it out, its there in the comments, and that is how i know that there is a problem

Comment: Your regex works for me. Please give more context and examples.

Comment: This is the change that i made, but same thing happend:    fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll("\\s*([,.?!\"\'()-:*;])\\s*", " $1 ");
        fileContent = Matcher.quoteReplacement(fileContent);
        System.out.println(fileContent);

Comment: What strings are not working?? "That's cool" works pretty good

Comment: I dont know how else to explain this, that's what the problem is :/

Comment: Its not specific strings, i have a text file that this code is supposed to tokenize on some words it works on some it doesn't

Comment: On which words it does not work? Is it a secret?))

Comment: Here is a line of text that its not working on and also at some point it is: `Karachi’s Manghopir area , DawnNews reported on Saturday . The `

Comment: Now it makes sense, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have another type of apostrophes in your string where it is failing.

```
Karachi’s Manghopir area , DawnNews reported on Saturday . The
```

In that string you have `’`
But in your regex you have `'`

Those are differrent. Add former apostrophe to your regex also, and it will work:

```
fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll("\\s*([,.?!\"'’()-:*;])\\s*", " $1 ");
```

Comment: Thank you, btw how did you get the other apostrophe? i cant seem to locate it :/

Comment: I have just copied it from your string which you provided) It's Unicode value is 8217, see more info here http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

From the Java API: **Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see** `Matcher.replaceAll`.**Use** `Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)` **to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired**

Comment: his is the change that i made, but same thing happend: fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll("\\s*([,.?!\"\'()-:*;])\\s*", " $1 "); fileContent = Matcher.quoteReplacement(fileContent); System.out.println(fileContent);